# Output Locale URLs in hreflang

Tags: localization

Just adding hreflang tags to the head on all pages of my multi-locale site...

```
{% for locale in craft.i18n.getSiteLocales() %}
    <link rel="alternate" href="{{ entry.url }}" hreflang="{{ locale }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Nearly there, but obviously this outputs my list of locales with the entry url for the *current locale* only. What I need is to output the entry url for *each locale*. Anyone done this before?

Comment: The accepted answer works - however, beware that the `hreflang` attribute should not necessarily be the same format as Craft's `locale` values. Depending on your locales, you may need to translate them into their ISO equivalents for language and country. For example `en_ca` would become `en-CA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `{{ craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(locale.id).first().url }}` inside the for loop you have made?

Comment: Great, glad it sorted it for you, see you at the next craft meet up :P